# Remove grey outline from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, aura

I have created a lightning component which sits as an Action in my Service Console like this...

[image]

I am trying to remove the grey outline inside the box, I have tried setting CSS styles on the lightning card but it doesn't work.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">

    <lightning:card title="Send customer a text message" class="testclass">

        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning:input type="text" name="myNumber" aura:id="number" value="{!v.simpleRecord.CaseNumber}" label="Customer Number" class="slds-m-bottom_xx-small"/>
            <lightning:textarea name="yourMessage" aura:id="message" label="Your message" required="true"/>

            <br/>
            <lightning:button label="Send" iconName="utility:sms" iconPosition="right" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.onSubmit}" />
        </p>
    </lightning:card>

</aura:component>
```

**Style**

```
.THIS {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.THIS .testclass {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can make the entire background white?

Comment: It looks like the grey border comes from the container of the code you just posted. I think it comes from the tab and not the card.

Comment: Anyway we can get rid of it? The next tab, a standard one has a white background so not sure why our own ones have grey backgrounds.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without the whole code.

Comment: @MartinLezer What other code do you need? The only thing I have omitted is the `aura:atribute` and `force:recorddata` tags, but they don't affect the layout surely.